# What is this file: .readahead doing in my root directory?

Tags: files, root, root-filesystem

When I do:

`ls -a /`

on Fedora 21 there is a hidden file named:

`.readahead` and it's 104092k

What is this file?.... is it suppose to be there?

**I found this on google:**

[readahead system call on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readahead).

Excerpt:

> readahead is a system call of the Linux kernel that loads a file's
>   contents into the page cache, providing that way a file prefetching
>   technology. When a file is subsequently accessed, its contents are
>   read from the main memory (RAM) rather than from a hard disk drive
>   (HDD), resulting in much lower file access latencies due to much
>   higher performance of the main memory.

[More on the readahead system call from man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html):

Excerpt:

> readahead() initiates readahead on a file so that subsequent reads
>          from that file will be satisfied from the cache, and not block on
>          disk I/O (assuming the readahead was initiated early enough and that
>          other activity on the system did not in the meantime flush pages from
>          the cache).

**The only hit for this particular file** was this mailing-list:

[http://linux.derkeiler.com](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/SuSE/2011-11/msg01561.html)

Excerpt:

> Indeed those files appear to be misplaced, the .config directory look
>   like a leftover from the installation.. and the .readahead file
>   appears to be written at boot time, dunno what writes it, monitoring
>   it with "audit" may yield some clues.
>
> File a bug report.

Comment: _systemd-readahead-done.service is executed a short while after boot completed and signals systemd-readahead-collect.service to end data collection. On this signal, this service will then sort the collected disk accesses and store information about them in_ [`/.readahead`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-readahead-replay.service.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank's to @don_crissti for the link: [systemd-readahead-replay.service.html](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-readahead-replay.service.html), here is what this file does.

Excerpt:

> **systemd-readahead-collect.service is a service that collects disk
>   usage patterns at boot time. systemd-readahead-replay.service is a
>   service that replays this access data collected at the subsequent
>   boot. Since disks tend to be magnitudes slower than RAM**, this is
>   **intended to improve boot speeds** by pre-loading early at boot all data
>   on disk that is known to be read for the complete boot process.
>
> systemd-readahead-done.service is executed a short while after boot
>   completed and signals systemd-readahead-collect.service to end data
>   collection. On this signal, this service will then sort the collected
>   disk accesses **and store information about them in /.readahead**.
>
> Normally, both systemd-readahead-collect.service and
>   systemd-readahead-replay.service are activated at boot so that access
>   patterns from the preceding boot are replayed and new data collected
>   for the subsequent boot. However, on read-only media where the
>   collected data cannot be stored, it might be a good idea to disable
>   systemd-readahead-collect.service.
>
> On rotating media, when replaying disk accesses at early boot,
>   systemd-readahead-replay.service will order read requests by their
>   location on disk. On non-rotating media, they will be ordered by their
>   original access timestamp. If the file system supports it,
>   systemd-readahead-collect.service will also defragment and rearrange
>   files on disk to optimize subsequent boot times.